# Could not resolve placeholder from properties file while importing XML

Tags: xml, spring, properties, placeholder

I am havinng trouble loading a parameter which is defined in a property file with spring context 3.2.4.RELEASE. My `web-application-context.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT" ignore-resource-not-found="false" ignore-unresolvable="false" location="file:${runtime.dir}/config/properties.txt" />

  <import resource="test-${myBooleanParameter}.xml" />
```

My `properties.txt` looks like this:

```
myBooleanParameter=true
```

In my `web.xml` is the following snippet:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>classpath:web-application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunatly I am getting this error:

```
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [web-application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'myBooleanParameter' in string value "test-${myBooleanParameter}.xml"
```

I looked into the sources he is using and I think the right propertySource is not even registering the `PropertySource`. This is the List of `propertySources`in `PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue`:

[image: propertySources]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkQM2.png

Full debug log can be found here: http://tny.cz/0ec9c339

Comment: `import` is handled before `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (what the propery placeholder is). At the moment of parsing the `import` only system or environmet properties will be used. Not property files as those aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Until Spring 3.0 this is true. From 3.1 forward it should be possible: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Comment: It would work if you would use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to load the properties as a `PropertySource` and register it with the `Environment`. It still will not work with a property-placeholder as that is loaded/processed after the import statement which is the whole point why the property-placeholder approach will not work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a piece of code like this one? https://gist.github.com/rponte/3989915

Comment: Too bad. But thank you for your help.
This question is then answered for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Class that can be used to accomplish this:

https://github.com/PE-INTERNATIONAL/org.spring.utils